# Gitlab CI caching particular file type

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use caching in gitlab runner, which builds a Maven Java project. Currently Gitlab runner only allow caching specific paths defined in gitlab yaml file in the `cache:` clause. When maven builds projects, it generate everything inside `target/` folder, which are untracked files in git. So I can simply use `untracked: true` option to cache everything under `target/` folder. The purpose of caching is to skip compiling the files, which have already been compiled by maven under the `target/` folder.

However this cache amounts to about 6GB, which is completely unreasonable for its size and time required to create and restore such a giant cache. It caches all jar and war artifacts built during compiling multi-module maven project. However, maven only needs .class files to check changes for re-compilation

So if their was some way using which I can cache only `*.class` files, and make them available in subsequent builds, then maven could check the .class files and skip re-compiling unchanged files and cache size would also be pretty small. Currently gitlab-runner only allow specifying absolute paths for caching. It does not support regex patterns for paths such as `\.class$` (which would have been very useful).

Is there any way I could cache only specific file types using gitlab runner yaml settings?

Comment: Maybe a silly idea but... can't you do a clean-up of that folder at the end of the job so as to get rid of everything except for the files that you want to cache?

Answer (score 0):

So based on [cascaval's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772810/cascaval) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982415/gitlab-ci-caching-particular-file-type/38005726#comment63411799_37982415), I was able to figure out a solution.

At the end of maven build I ran a command to clean all build artifacts created by maven, which are not used for checking stale status of .java resources. Here is what I wrote -

```
cd ./projects/directory
find . | grep --perl-regexp --regexp='\/target\/(?!classes|maven)' | xargs rm --recursive --force
```

This saves all .class files in target/classes folder, including folder structure and also files in maven-status folder, which are probably used by maven to check file status for recompilation.

Comment: I would suggest using `find *` to exclude the `.git` directory. Furthermore, you probably want to include `test-classes` as well.